# How to change a value to zero, using a loop?

Tags: r, loops

The below loop is used to prepare data before I perform survival analyses. `Vector_B` should be turned to '0' based on the maximum value (= days) in `Vector_A`. In this example I want the maximum value to be '10'. I already know how to use the ifelse-function for this, but I really want to know how to implement loops instead (in this case a for loop).

Could you help me out with the script below? I want `Vector_B` to change to ''0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0'') because at every `Vector_A` higher than 10, `Vector_B` should be '0'.

Code:

```
Vector_A <- c(7, 17, 5, 12, 7, 13) 
Vector_B <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1) 
for (i in Vector_A) if (i > 10) {(Vector_B <- 0)}
```

Outcome:

> Vector_A: 7 17  5 12  7 13

> Vector_B: 0

Comment: You're potentially reassigning `Vector_B` at every iteration, rather than changing a single value in the vector. You would want to use `Vector_B[i]`. But this misses out on one of R's strengths which is that many functions are vectorized and don't need loops. Your loop would be better written as `Vector_B <- ifelse(Vector_A > 10, 0, 1)`

Comment: Another vectorized option `Vector_B[Vector_A > 10] <- 0`

Comment: @camille: your `ifelse` gives a different result (not what @MSikking wanted), because it sets `Vector_B` always to 1 if `Vector_A > 10`, but it should stay 0 if it was 0 before. See below.

Comment: @nachti you're right, I was focused on switching it over to an `ifelse` operation. Regardless, no need for a `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an odd way of doing things as there exist R function already for this but seeing as you explicitly asked for a loop try this.

```
for (i in 1:length(Vector_A)){
  Vector_B[i] <- ifelse(Vector_A[i] > 10, 0 ,Vector_B[i])
}
```

Comment: At this point you could just stick with an `if` / `else`, since you're only checking one value at a time

Comment: `ifelse` is already vectorized, so `Vector_B <- ifelse(Vector_A > 10, 0, Vector_B)` would do the job (if this is, what you want -- it's not clear for me ...)

Comment: yep, aware of this, but he/she asked for a loop so mainly wanted to demo why their assignment wasn't working